# Stopping a video stream when UIViewController is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIWebView` with the URL pointing to a video on my website which loads and streams fine when the page is opened.

I then have a Back button on the same page to take me back using a segue. However if I use this button to return the video continues to play in the background. I presume the segue does not actually close the view but just pushes the new view in front.

Can anyone advise me as to what I ought to do to either close the view or to stop the video downloading when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewWillDisappear:` you can call `stopLoading` on the web view, which will stop any requests that are still loading, followed by `loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]` to remove any loaded content.  You can also send `nil` to `loadRequest:` (which as of iOS 6 has the same effect as the about:blank request) but that behavior isn't documented and could change in future releases.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.webView stopLoading];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
}
```